# Why BFC can eliminate the gap between div and body?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
        <style>
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding:0;
            }
            div{
                background-color:lightblue;
               
            }
            p{
                margin: 40px;
                background-color:black;
                color: white;
                width:200px;
                
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecte
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

When I add "overflow:auto" in div stylesheet, it shows:

[image]

While without this line, it shows:

[image]

Except making div block BFC by `overflow:auto`, specifying border or padding value can reach the same result.
Before specifying the border attribute, the shape of div relies on its child which is the `<p>` block. so the top of `<p>` and `<div>` are same even there is a margin value of `<p>`.
By specifying the border or padding-top which can shape div. that why the gap eliminated.
But I can not figure out why making div BFC still have the same effect.
anyone can explain this to me?

Comment: what exactly is BFC?

Comment: @decpk Block Formatting Context

Comment: you are looking at the wrong phenomenon, you are dealing with margin-collapsing and the Creation of BCF disable margin collapsing

Comment: @TemaniAfif You solved my problem. Thanks mate.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I find some highly voted answer, how can I favorite it? new user not familiar with it and also checked out all the menu on the site. Cannot find it!

Comment: @zep you can only favorite a question not an answer OR you can follow an answer. It's not the same as favorite but you can have them listed in your profile under followed post

Comment: @Brian Tompsett Thanks for your careful proofreading.